# AttributeError: module Testing has no attribute LDA

Tags: python, attributeerror

I know there are many questions with this title, but every one I see does not solve my problem.
Basically My file tree is like this:

```
- Main folder
    - Testing
        - LDA.py
    - run_tests.py
```

in run_tests.py when I try to import LDA from Testing with `from Testing import LDA`, I get the error: module 'testing' has no attribute 'LDA'.
I don't think I did anything wrong bc on Windows this error does not happen but only on my fedora machine.

EDIT:
This error does not appear if I create a new project and try to import some files im the main. I assume the problem is bc it's a personal repo that I cloned from github?
Maybe the files are organised wrong in there

Comment: Try to add a `__init__.py` inside `Testing`. It should work.

Comment: I already tried since I saw this answer on another post, but it doesn't work.